# Leanback crash ListRowPresenter when Scroll

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, listrowpresenter

I have problem with **Leanback** `ListRowPresenter` on **android TV** application.
some time this scroll to left or right , the application crashed.

I search some solution but find the answer *"caused by work on main(ui) thread"* but my project work on sub thread's and UI has minimum task.

**My `Logcat` when crash occurred**:

```
system_process E/ActivityManager: ANR in <package name> (<package name>.MainActivity)
   PID: 6764
   Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send key event because the focused window has not finished processing all of the input events that were previously delivered to it.  Outbound queue length: 0.  Wait queue length: 1.)
   Load: 0.9 / 0.39 / 0.18
   CPU usage from 208977ms to 0ms ago (2018-05-27 09:51:27.527 to 2018-05-27 09:54:56.505):
     0.4% 1306/surfaceflinger: 0.1% user + 0.3% kernel
     0.3% 1611/system_server: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 6915 minor
     0.2% 1311/audioserver: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 3 minor
     0.1% 1327/adbd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3442 minor
     0.1% 2215/com.estrongs.android.pop: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1198 minor 1 major
     0.1% 2405/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2389 minor
     0% 2073/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 344 minor
     0% 1812/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 171 minor
     0% 2121/com.google.android.leanbacklauncher: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 851 minor
     0% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1255/logd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 19 minor
     0% 2255/com.android.defcontainer: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 248 minor
     0% 1253/jbd2/vdc-8: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 6289/logcat: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 7/migration/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 12/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 682/kworker/u4:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1247/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1302/healthd: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1305/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 1322/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 217 minor
     0% 1828/sdcard: 0% user + 0% kernel
     0% 2153/com.google.android.leanbacklauncher.recommendations: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 24 minor
     0% 2551/.esfm: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
     0% 6292/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 6764/<package name>: 0% user + 0% kernel
   34% TOTAL: 33% user + 1.1% kernel + 0% iowait + 0.1% softirq
   CPU usage from 329ms to 835ms later (2018-05-27 09:54:56.834 to 2018-05-27 09:54:57.339):
     99% 6764/<package name>: 99% user + 0% kernel
       100% 6764/an.<app name>: 100% user + 0% kernel
     1.9% 1611/system_server: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
   51% TOTAL: 51% user + 0% kernel
```

a changed my package name to **< package name >**

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug for Leanback support library which has been fixed in revision 27.0.0. You can find bug fixes introduced in this revision [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions#bug-fixes_4)